# Detect unlock screen using Javascript on website

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm trying to find out answer to my problem, but Google and other sites can't help me.

I'm building mobile website and I need redirect to homepage where browser is reactivated (unlock screen or open from minimalized). Is it possible?

Thanks a lot

Comment: As far as I know there's no general HTML/JavaScript API for that. But you might research how different onfocus events behave on smartphone. Just in case you are actually writing an app, take a look at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume

Comment: Wow, that is behavior that would make me stop using that app/site pretty quickly. *(No dv from me, I don't quite understand why people are downvoting this question.)*

Comment: It's for security reason

Comment: This is a Ok Question and if your site is a Web Application you might need this however Application says it all most Web Applications have an independent mobile Application for security concerns

Answer (score 1):

No in short,

There is no specified way to detect a lock screen as such there is nothing in HTML / Javascript.

However you could use <s>PhoneGap</s> Cordova and create a mobile application,
I have a [class](http://www.jsclasses.org/package/170-JavaScript-Manage-event-handlers-in-PhoneGap-applications.html) to make events in PhoneGap easy

then you can use Application paused if you still want your application to only work online you can use an AJAX loader to load the content as using <s>PhoneGap</s> Cordova dose not hit the Cross-Origin domain policies of JavaScript normally

This i think is the only alternative you can use and it would require quite a bit of work to make your site become a mobile application.

**EDIT:**

Sorry a bit of Detail. <s>PhoneGap</s> Cordova allows you to build mobile applications HTML, CSS & JavaScript and provides some new events into JavaScript to help with mobile applications as well as the ability to call upon the hardware of a phone you can find more out at
<s>http://phonegap.com/</s> https://cordova.apache.org/

**Another Thought:**

Thanks to @jeroenk for this idea it just came to me after reading his you might be able to do a little hack fix.

on your page

```
window.timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);

setInterval(4000, function(){
  var curTime = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
  if(curTime > window.timestamp+5){
     // do redirect
  }
  window.timestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
});
```

I'm not 100% but i think Javascript gets halted when the browser on a mobile is not open, so lock screen on minimized so the above will check every 4 seconds that the Javascript has not become out of sink in (allowing for 1 second extra in case there is an application lag it would take some one more than 1 second to get though lock screen unless it was the user using the phone so it was not put down)

As i say this is a thought it might not work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something with window.onunload event

Comment: this is not fired unless your redirect or close the tab on mobile browsers i don't think it fired if the browser is minimized (home button)

Comment: Thanks however you gave me an idea thats now in my answer :)